# How can I migrate cross-project branches via cvs2git?

Tags: git, tags, branch, cvs, cvs2git

I am migrating an old cvs repository to git. Therefore i try to migrate each project separately. But there are branches and tags which reference several projects. How can i handle this?

Is a migration of the whole cvs repository my only chance ? - in order to migrate all branches and tags in the right way?

I've found some setting options inside the OPTION-FILE of cvs2git:

> *In CVS, it is perfectly possible to make a single commit that affects more than one project or more than one branch of a single project. Subversion also allows such commits. Therefore, by default, when cvs2git sees what looks like a cross-project or cross-branch CVS commit, it converts it into a cross-project/cross-branch Subversion commit.
>   However, other tools and SCMs have trouble representing
>   cross-project or cross-branch commits. (For example, Trac's Revtree
>   plugin, http://www.trac-hacks.org/wiki/RevtreePlugin is confused by
>   such commits.) Therefore, we provide the following two options to
>   allow cross-project/cross-branch commits to be suppressed.
>   cvs2git only supports single-project conversions (multiple-project
>   conversions wouldn't really make sense for git anyway). So this
>   option must be set to False:
>   **ctx.cross_project_commits = False**
>   git itself doesn't allow commits that affect more than one branch,
>   so this option must be set to False:
>   **ctx.cross_branch_commits = False'***

How does this suppression work? What would be if I set both parameters to true?